# Module configuration and language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have created a configuration object which looks like:

```
message: 'Here we go!'
langcode: en
```

And I've created a form which allows me to change that message. However, I am not entirely sure how to work with translations for this message.

Ideally, I would want to display fields for each language in my module settings. 
And how can I retrieve the translation for that message?

Currently I can grab that message using the following code, but I cannot figure out how it works with language translation, and how I could render a form for each language available.

```
  $config = \Drupal::config('my_module.settings');
  $message = $config->get('message');
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?